# How to get count of only visible colums in a WPF datagrid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

How can I get count of only visible columns in a WPF datagrid. I am using the count to navigate through the colums present in the datagrid.

```
 if (getSelectedRow().IsEditing)
                    {
                        if (dataGrid.SelectedCells.Count != 0)
                        {
                            int columnDisplayIndex = dataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex + 1;

                            if (columnDisplayIndex <= dataGrid.Columns.Count)
                            {
                                if (columnDisplayIndex == dataGrid.Columns.Count)

                                {
                                    row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));

                                    nextColumn = dataGrid.ColumnFromDisplayIndex(nextCol(1) - 1);
                                    dataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dataGrid.SelectedItem, nextColumn);

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    e.Handled = true;
                                    nextColumn = dataGrid.ColumnFromDisplayIndex(nextCol(columnDisplayIndex));
                                    dataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dataGrid.SelectedItem, nextColumn);
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        if (isNotComboBox())
                        {
                            dataGrid.CommitEdit();
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question cause I'm not into WPF, but isn't there a "Visible" property on those columns ?

Comment: show us a little code and tell us what you have tried out!

Comment: @ sexta: Here code is irrelevant as I want to correct the code structure a bit since I didn't get the visible column count of a datagrid. But its not safe for future change so I have to get a proper solution.

Comment: Don't you want to get the Columns list and check if they are visible or not? dataGrid.Columns.Where(x => x.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)?

Comment: What do you mean not safe for future?  Are you worried the Visibility property might go away?  And please format the code so we don't have to scroll to the right.

Comment: @Blam, Sorry, I will keep in mind the points u mentioned in my next post.